# Exactly what are these 2 error messages telling me?

Tags: dependencies

Heimdall is program used for rooting a Samsung Galaxy S II phone (and other Android phones).

When I attempt to open (with the GDebi Package installer) the Heimdall Frontend 1.3.1 binary for Debian Linux (AMD64 / Intel 64), I get this error message:

Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: heimdall (>= 1.3.0)

I also get the following error message when I try to open (again with the GDebi Package installer) the Heimdall 1.3.1 Command Line binary for Debian Linux (AMD64 / Intel 64):

Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libusb-1.0-0 (>= 2:1.0.8)

What do I need to do so as not to get these error messages.  I'm running 64-bit Karmic, but others running Ubuntu 11.10 are getting similar messages.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the Heimdall website, the author clearly states that:

   > To be able to Install Heimdall-Frontend, Heimdall (Commandline) must be installed first.

so install heimdall (commandline)  first.

2.The library you have is outdated, you need a newer libusb version.

I'm running Xubuntu 11.10, and I have installed Heimdall, and I didn't get the libusb error, since you're using karmic.. U_P_G_R_A_D_E.